# Session state in gRPC

Tags: grpc, grpc-node

Does gRPC have the notion of session state? Can I keep state associated with a session, such as to allow a client to incrementally build a data structure, and garbage collect it when the session ends?

Answer (score 1):

gRPC is based on request/response semantics. You could try streaming request from client to server to build your DS incrementally in the same RPC call.